# Remover tags web, aplicação-web e aplicação-desktop?

Tags: debate, tags

Temos essas 3 tags que não me dizem muita coisa, pelo menos não da maneira como estão sendo usadas:

- [web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web)
- [aplicação-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web)
- [aplicação-desktop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-desktop)

Estou pensando em removê-las, alguém tem algo contra?

---

Aproveito para pedir que quem puder identifique tags problemáticas, consertando por conta própria (tags sem perguntas são excluídas por um script de madrugada), ou abrindo um debate aqui no meta. Dá pra melhorar muita coisa na organização do site, mas precisa ser em mutirão para dar certo.

Comment: Mande-as para o limbo! Se possível, dê uma olhada [nessa tags](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2362/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-sugerir-um-sin%c3%b4nimo) também.

Comment: Esse post tem mais de uma ano e nao foi feito nada em relacao ás tags se tive reparado deixava-o morto ahah. As tags nao estao causando problema. Entretanto [tag:web] foi marcada como sinónimo de [tag:aplicacao-web]. No meu ver está tudo certo... PArece que há quem discorde...

Answer (score -4):

## Não! Não! Não!

Acho que faz todo sentido diferenciar [aplicacoes-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacoes-web) de [aplicacoes-desktop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacoes-desktop).
Principalmente a tag [aplicacoes-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacoes-web) pode fazer falta no mundo java.

Nesta outra pergunta que fala da [java-web](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5540/java-web-existe) ve-se bem isso!

Aliás eu na minha resposta eu sugeri exatamente o uso da tag [aplicacoes-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacoes-web) para destingir que se trata duma aplicação web.

Elas podem eventualmente estar a serem mal usadas, mas elimina-las nao é o caminho certo!

Tente encontrar outras solucoes tal como acrescentar descricóes nas tags, meter tags diferentes se estas não se aplicarem na pergunta... Qualquer coisa... mas não mate essas tags.

Comment: Deixem comentários a explicar porque é que nao concordam