# "Java web" existe?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Tem uma tag [java-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-web) no site com várias perguntas dentro. Isso é o nome oficial de alguma tecnologia? Ou é uma maneira de dizer "desenvolvimento Java para a web"? Faz sentido mesmo termos essa tag?

Comment: Tenho quase ctz que não.

Comment: Eu também, mas na dúvida achei melhor perguntar

Comment: Por mim pode matar... Não vejo valor nenhum nessa tag. Já temos tags específicas [tag:jsf], [tag:jsp], etc .

Comment: Nao existe. O correto seria aplicar a tag [tag:java] e [tag:aplicação-web] e matar essa tag

Comment: É quase a mesma coisa que criar uma tag `javascript-desktop`, *desnecessauro*. **:)**

Comment: Quando vi o título da pergunta, cliquei com certeza de que ia migrar pro site principal :D

Comment: @Gabe é que não consegui fazer um título com trocadilho, então apelei pra pegadinha :D

Comment: @BrunoCosta Poste uma resposta com a sua sugestão. Posso até dizer que a tag faz sentido de existir no presente, mas se for proposta uma coisa melhor que venha a substitui-la em um futuro próximo, ela poderia vir a se tornar desnecessária.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removi a tag das 55 perguntas em que ela aparecia, e coloquei [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) no lugar. Tinha 19 dessas perguntas **sem** a tag de Java!

Answer (score 10):

É uma maneira de descrever "desenvolvimento Java para a web". Ou seja, um termo guarda-chuva/genérico para englobar coisas referentes a Servlets, JSP, JSF, web-services, VRaptor, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, REST, SOA, Spring MVC, EJB, Primefaces, etc. (embora para ser sincero, algumas destas tecnologias dizem respeito a sistemas distribuídos, e não a sistemas web).

Ao meu ver é uma tag válida, embora não me oponha a sua eliminação e também a considero bastante propensa de se utilizar inadequadamente.

Comment: Concordo. Pelo que aprendi de desenvolvimento Java para internet, me coloco na posição de alguém que entenda de todas essas tecnologias e gostaria de um sinal forte de que uma pergunta tem a ver com elas - mesmo que o AP não saiba na hora.

Comment: @Gabe Mas a pergunta teria a ver com uma parte dessas tecnologias, não todas. Portanto tem tags mais específicas. Estou achando que essa tag é como a tag "web", que eliminamos há algum tempo.

Comment: @bfavaretto É aí que meu conhecimento sobre Java me falha, pra julgar o quão específica e restritiva a tag realmente é, e defiro à quem sabe muito mais. No pouco que eu sei, "java web" como termo, se refere à um um conjunto bem menor de opções do que "python web", por exemplo, e é daí que ela pode ter valor.

Answer (score 3):

A técnologia java-web não existe e por isso eu creio que deveriam ser usadas tags existentes para substituir.

Conforme sugeri nos comentários uma boa opção seria aplicar as tags [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e [aplicação-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web/info). Contudo o @Vitor Stafusa sugere que nem todas as perguntas dizem respeito a aplicacóes web, mas dizem respeito a sistemas distribuídos.

Nesses casos creio que seria bom aplicar as tags [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e [sistemas-distribuídos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sistemas-distribu%c3%addos).

Para além disso se for importante também podem ser acrescentadas com outras tecnologias/plataformas/frameworks, tais como [java-ee](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee), [spring](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring), ou outras...

Answer (score 1):

**Java** e **Web**, as duas tecnologias que atendem perfeitamente esta especificação são:

1. [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start)
2. [Java EE Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition)

Acredito que são tecnologias diferentes, portanto **é melhor descartar esta tag**, e usar tags mais específicas.

Answer (score -4):

acho que a melhor solução é mudar para `java-ee`